# How to write Delete Handler in ReactJS that will also remove data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am looking to create a onClick handler where I can remove selected data from Firebase as well as remove the selected list rendered on the page. The code below shows how I retrieve the data from firebase and rendered it to my webpage using ReactJS. I also attached a image of my data from firebase.

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import database, {User} from '../firebase-setup.js'
import classes from './WatchListPage.css'

class WatchListPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listOfShows: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    database.ref('shows/' + User.user.uid).on('child_added', snapshot => {
      const newList = this.state.listOfShows;
      newList.push({
        showId: snapshot.key,
        title: snapshot.val().title,
        genre: snapshot.val().genre
      });
      this.setState({
        listOfShows: newList
      });
      console.log('test', JSON.stringify(newList))
    });
  }



  render() {
    const listOfShows = this.state.listOfShows.map((show) =>
      <li key={show.showId}>
        {show.title} {show.genre}
      </li>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        {listOfShows}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default WatchListPage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve it.

1) Going by your code. Implement a onClick handler which will remove the item from firebase as well as from your state list. I haven't implemented the error cases where firebase write fails. If required we can also implement some loading screen when we are deleting something from firebase.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import database, {User} from '../firebase-setup.js'
import classes from './WatchListPage.css'

class WatchListPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listOfShows: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    database.ref('shows/' + User.user.uid).on('child_added', snapshot => {
      const newList = this.state.listOfShows;
      newList.push({
        showId: snapshot.key,
        title: snapshot.val().title,
        genre: snapshot.val().genre
      });
      this.setState({
        listOfShows: newList
      });
      console.log('test', JSON.stringify(newList))
    });
  }



  render() {
    const listOfShows = this.state.listOfShows.map((show, index) =>
      <li key={show.showId} onClick={this.removeShow.bind(this, index)}>
        {show.title} {show.genre}
      </li>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        {listOfShows}
      </div>
    );
  }

  removeShow(index) {

    let showItem = this.state.listOfShows[index];
    database.ref('shows/' + User.user.uid +'/'+ showItem.showId).remove();
    this.state.listOfShows.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({listOfShows: this.state.listOfShows });
  }

}      

export default WatchListPage
```

2) I would like to go with this approach if the data is not too big. It will improve the performance of your app also.

Firstly, we should always implement the data fetching in componentWillMount() instead of componentDidMount(), why wait for component to render to fetch some external data.

Second, instead of having a 'child_added' listener implement a 'value' listener since you want to show all the data anyway. Having child_added listener will update the state every time it fetched one child, leading to multiple renders ie. if there are 5 children then it will render for 5 times. Whereas using 'value' listener will fetch data only once until it is changed. Lets dive into code, you will get a better understanding.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import database, {User} from '../firebase-setup.js'
import classes from './WatchListPage.css'

class WatchListPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listOfShows: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.handler = database.ref('shows/' + User.user.uid).on('value', snapshot => {
      const showList = snapshot.val();
      let newList = [];
      for(let showId in showList) {
         newList.push({
            showId: showId,
            title: showList[showId].title,
            genre: showList[showId].genre
         });
      }

      this.setState({
        listOfShows: newList
      });
      console.log('test', JSON.stringify(newList))
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    database.ref('shows/' + User.user.uid).off('value', this.handler);
  }



  render() {
    const listOfShows = this.state.listOfShows.map((show) =>
      <li key={show.showId} onClick={this.removeShow.bind(this, show.showId)}>
        {show.title} {show.genre}
      </li>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        {listOfShows}
      </div>
    );
  }

  removeShow(showId) {
    database.ref('shows/' + User.user.uid +'/'+ showId).remove();
  }

}

export default WatchListPage
```

See how simplified is the removeShow() method in 2nd approach. You don't need to manipulate your state since it is all synced with firebase because of 'value' listener. Also check, I  have implemented the componentWillUnmount() method. Its always good to remove 'on' listeners before destroying component else it will lead to memory leak.